# add tab in admin dashboard magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, dashboard

Copy `Ordered.php`

From

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Tab/Products
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Tab/Products
```

Rename `New.php`

I have modified the following code:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Tab_Products_New extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('productsNewGrid');
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Sales')) {
            return $this;
        }
        if ($this->getParam('website')) {
            $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
            $storeId = array_pop($storeIds);
        } else if ($this->getParam('group')) {
            $storeIds = Mage::app()->getGroup($this->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
            $storeId = array_pop($storeIds);
        } else {
            $storeId = (int)$this->getParam('store');
        }

        $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());


        $collection
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                    )
              );


        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Product Name'),
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'product_name'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('price', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Price'),
            'width'     => '120px',
            'type'      => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => (string) Mage::app()->getStore((int)$this->getParam('store'))->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'product_price'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Quantity Ordered'),
            'width'     => '120px',
            'align'     => 'right',
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'qty_ordered',
            'type'      => 'number'
        ));

        $this->setFilterVisibility(false);
        $this->setPagerVisibility(false);

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /*
     * Returns row url to show in admin dashboard
     * $row is bestseller row wrapped in Product model
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $row
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        // getId() would return id of bestseller row, and product id we get by getProductId()
        $productId = $row->getProductId();

        // No url is possible for non-existing products
        if (!$productId) {
            return '';
        }

        $params = array('id' => $productId);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
            $params['store'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        }
        return $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product/edit', $params);
    }
}
```

Then Copy `Grids.php`

From

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/
```

added the following code:

```
$this->addTab('new_products', array(
        'label'     => $this->__('New Product'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_tab_products_new')->toHtml(),
        'class'     => 'ajax'
));
```

I want to add a new product tab in admin dashboard,beside customers.I don't know what wrong with the `New.php`.I click the new product tab,it's not working.How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to get this working with only a few more lines to change.

Update the Dashboard controller Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController to add the new action

```
public function productsNewAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Update the admin layout.xml design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\main.xml to add the new section

```
<adminhtml_dashboard_productsnew>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/dashboard_tab_products_new" name="adminhtml.dashboard.tab.products.new"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_dashboard_productsnew>
```

The you would just need to update your code in the Grids.php to the following.

```
$this->addTab('new_products', array(
    'label'     => $this->__('New Product'),
    'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/productsNew', array('_current'=>true)),
    'class'     => 'ajax'
));
```

This should then work using a call to the url rather than the block content.

You then need to select the attributes you want to show. You can do this by selecting all or by attribute code.

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

Important is the column index defined in _prepareColumns match these attribute codes Otherwise you will just get an empty row.

I would suggest packaging these changes into a new module with a controller, layout.xml and block files. There are lots of great tutorials around on how to do this, but obviously you don't have to :)

Comment: Used your code is working,but nothing data to output.I think something wrong with `$collection` in `new.php`.Can you give me some help?

Comment: The problem with your New.php appears to be in the line $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds()); after removing this line it worked for me

Comment: Before removed `$collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->get‌​VisibleInCatalogIds());` output 'No records found.'.After removed it then output 7 line,but nothing data in it.Why I have not the same result with you?

Comment: You need to select the items you want to display. Using $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name'); then the index on the column must match the attribute code selected.

Comment: No problem, I am glad my help was useful.

Comment: Copy `DashboardController.php` from `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers` to `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers`,add `public function productsNewAction()`,why not working?